# How to do load balancing using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I tried to achieve load balancing using camel and using the below code to get the response from server.But, the rest service is not called.

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                System.out.println("inside configure....");
                from(
                        "http://localhost:9876/LunaHSMLoadBalancer/csr/getSignature")
                        .loadBalance()
                        .roundRobin()
                        .to("http://localhost:8080/test/services/token/signature",
                                "http://10.65.49.216:8080/test/services/token/signature");
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(900000);
        context.stop();
```

Comment: if you add `.log("...")` statements both before the `.loadBalance()` line, and after the `.roundRobin()` line, what happens?